# Passing the value of a HTML list to EditorFor method OR directly to controller

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I am doing the CRUD for the table called **Recipe**. The whole functionality is already created in an API and at this point, I am trying to implement it on a web page. During the creation of a new recipe, you have to complete some fields such as *TotalTimeUnitId*. This is a column in the Recipe table that only takes integers; however, in the user interface you have to pick from a list with seconds/minutes/hours, their value being the thing that needs to be passed in the database through the controller.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalTimeUnitId)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalTimeUnitId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalTimeUnitId)

        <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedtValue();">
            <option value="1">seconds</option>
            <option value="2">minutes</option>
            <option value="3">hours</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            function getSelectedtValue() {
                var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
                console.log(selectedValue);
            }
            getSelectedtValue();
        </script>
```

This is the code that I wrote trying to achieve this. If you pick, let's say, *minutes* from the list, the `getSelectedValue()` function returns "2". How can I be able to call this method inside the EditorFor so the variable TotalTimeUnitId will be assigned the value? Is there another way to doing this?

Comment: Can't you just use a `DropDownListFor(model => model.TotalTimeUnitId, ...)` with a list of text/values, instead of an `EditorFor`?

Comment: Oh, does it work like that? I didn't really know how to use DropDownListFor so I just went for this solution. I will try it out and come back with updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
       model => model.TotalTimeUnitId,
       new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{
                   new { value = 1 , text = "Seconds"  },
                   new { value = 2 , text = "Minutes" },
                   new { value = 3 , text = "Hours"}
                },
              "value",
              "text",
               Model.TotalTimeUnitId
       )
    )
```

This did the job.